# IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.time.LocalDateTime field to java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, h2

I am doing test task for a self-teaching. 
My stack is Spring Boot/H2 date base/Hibernate

I have like a REST-full service (actually it is not, now I am trying to fix it)

I've been told that I have a lot of bad code decisions and mistakes, so I've decide to fix it. 
Initial state of a working project is there - https://github.com/iliapastushenko/testtaskREST

I've started to refactor that and first thing that I've made - got rid of 
jackson-datatype-jsr310 because it is actually redundant thing for me - I've deleted it from POM and ClientappApplication class and edited my Application class field "dateCreated":

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
@Type(type="timestamp")
private LocalDateTime dateCreated;
```

So, when I am trying to get one application of needed client via frontend 
I get this type of Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.time.LocalDateTime 
field root.Model.Application.dateCreated to java.sql.Timestamp
```

Could you please give me a hint - what is wrong ?

Comment: Which Version of hibernate do you use?

Comment: @Jens I am using Spring Boot 1.5.8.RELEASE which has 5.0.12.Final Hibernate inside according to the documentation - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.8.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by property:

```
<hibernate.version>5.2.12.Final</hibernate.version>
```

So, since Hibernate 5.2 everything is okay with LocalDateTime, not Hibernate 5.0 as I was told earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Use hibernate-convertors to convert LocalDateTime to java.sql.Timestamp. You can create a hibernate converter like the one below:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

@Override
public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
    return (locDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(locDate));
}

@Override
public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
    return (sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate());
}
}
```

For more details, look here: https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/

Comment: yap, I've found this solution via google before - but it does not work for me. I think this is kind of outdated. And second thing - this is too difficult I think. There must be some plain solution.

Comment: I don't know an easier solution.