# How to use LocalDateTime with Hibernate raw sql query?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to use hibernate to generate pojo with raw sql:

```
// the query code
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
UserDetailResponse detail = (UserDetailResponse) session.createSQLQuery(sql)
                        .setParameter("uid", id)
                  .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(UserDetailResponse.class)).uniqueResult();

// the pojo
    public class UserDetailResponse {
        private int id;
        private BigDecimal totalSettleAmount;
        private LocalDateTime lastSettleTime;
    
        public BigDecimal getTotalSettleAmount() {
            return totalSettleAmount;
        }
    
        public void setTotalSettleAmount(BigDecimal totalSettleAmount) {
            this.totalSettleAmount = totalSettleAmount;
        }
    
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
    
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        public LocalDateTime getLastSettleTime() {
            return lastSettleTime;
        }
    
        public void setLastSettleTime(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
            this.lastSettleTime = localDateTime;
        }
    }
```

However,hibernate complains an IllegalArgumentException:

```
ERROR 17676 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.p.access.spi.SetterMethodImpl        : HHH000123: IllegalArgumentException in class: io.loremipsum.test.dto.UserDetailResponse, setter method of property: lastSettleTime
ERROR 17676 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.p.access.spi.SetterMethodImpl        : HHH000091: Expected type: java.time.LocalDateTime, actual value: java.sql.Timestamp
```

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49357775/illegalargumentexception-can-not-set-java-time-localdatetime-field-to-java-sql), hibernate had support LocalDatetime since 5.2 while the version I am using is 5.4.20 Final.

Is there any configuration I miss?

Comment: Hibernate does, JDBC doesn't. You are using SQL with a plain mapping thus not supported. I would suggest to just write a JPQL and have that support.

Comment: @M.Deinum some other type,such as integer,string,bigdecimal work fine with such mapping.

Comment: Because those are nativly supported by JDBC whereas the `java.time` classes are not. As Hibernate/JPA is left out whilst mapping here (which is what normally does the conversion using an `AttributeConverter`) it doesn't work.